# Submitting time data to wikibase with `wbcreateclaim` results in "invald-snak" error

Tags: python-requests, mediawiki-api, wikibase

I am currently trying to populate a wikidata instance via POST requests. For this purpose I use the `requests` library in Python together with the [MediaWiki API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=main).

So far I managed to create claims with different datatypes (like `String`, `Quantity`, `Wikidata items`, `Media` ...). The general scheme I use is this (with different `value` strings for each datatype):

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
# authenticate and obtain a csrf_token
parameters = {
    'action':   'wbcreateclaim',
    'format':   'json',
    'entity':   'Q1234',
    'snaktype': 'value',
    'property': 'P12',
    'value':    '{"time": "+2022-02-19T00:00:00Z", "timezone": 0, "precision": 11, "calendarmodel": "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727"}',
    'token':     csrf_token,
    'bot':       1,
}
        
r = session.post(api_url, data=parameters)
print(r.json())
```

Every attempt to insert data of type `time` leads to an `invalid-snak` error (info: "invalid snak data.").

The following changes did not solve the problem:

- submitting the value string as dictionary value (without the single quotes),
- putting the numeric values into (double) quotes,
- using a local item for the calendarmodel ("http://localhost:8181/entity/Q73"),
- adding `before` and `after` keys in the dictionary,
- omitting `timezone`, `precision`, `calendarmodel` and combinations thereof,
- formatting the `time` string as `2022-02-19`,
- submitting the request with administrator rights (though the error message does not
  suggest a problem with insufficient user rights).

Do you know, what I'm doing wrong here? What must the `value` field look like?

I am aware of the fact that special libraries or interfaces for exist for these tasks. But I do want to use the Wikidata API directly with the `requests` library in Python.

Thank you very much for your help!

Installed software versions:

- MediaWiki:  1.36.3
- PHP:        7.4.27
- MariaDB     10.3.32-MariaDB-1:10.3.32+maria~focal
- ICU         67.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if the value string is generated from the dictionary via `json.dumps()`.